# Not able to give separate color for multiple words

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a certain sentence. I have to give black color to four words in that sentence.

This is how I have attempted that...

In `viewDidLoad`,

```
rangeArray = ["Knowledge","Events","Community","Offers"]

    for text in rangeArray {
      let range = (bottomTextLabel.text! as NSString).range(of: text)

      let attribute = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: bottomTextLabel.text!)
      attribute.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.black , range: range)

      self.bottomTextLabel.attributedText = attribute
    }
```

But with this code, instead of having black color for all 4 words, I get only the word 'Offers' in black color. What am I doing wrong...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are updating the `self.bottomTextLabel.attributedText` for each run of the `for loop`.

Instead of that you must

1. create an `NSMutableAttributedString` using the `sentence`,
2. add all the relevant `attributes` as per your `rangeArray` and
3. then at last set that `attrStr` it as `attributedText` of `bottomTextLabel`.

Here is what I mean to say,

```
if let sentence = bottomTextLabel.text {
    let rangeArray = ["Knowledge","Events","Community","Offers"]
    let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: sentence)
    rangeArray.forEach {
        let range = (sentence as NSString).range(of: $0)
        attrStr.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.black, range: range)
    }
    self.bottomTextLabel.attributedText = attrStr
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PGDev.....it worked…Thank you..But I have a doubt..I know its silly…:).. $0 indicates the text. But what does $0 indicate in general in other scenarios also where $0 is used..?

Comment: $0 is refers to each element when you traverse an array in for-loop.

Comment: @asd2 `$0` is a Shorthand Argument Name in closure. Check [Shorthand Argument Names](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID100)